# Keep the auto increment value for in-memory database after restarting the server

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, in-memory-database

We are using [in-memory tables in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) with an auto-incremented primary key.

After restarting MySQL the in-memory tables are emptied as expected.

However we would like to keep the auto increment value, so that the next inserted row will have the ID after the one that was used in the last session.

Is that possible?

Comment: it's usually fine to repeat the ID a couple times, I just can't start from 1 again since we use the IDs for some other controls

Comment: You can specify the auto increment value at the end of your create table command, check the docs

Comment: which one? I couldnt find in the above url

Comment: I could run `ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;` however how can I trigger this command while starting the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could not use the `ALTER TABLE` statement because a function was necessary to calculate the initial auto increment.

The solution was to:

1. `my.cnf` file was changed, after the header `[mysqld]` we added `init-file = [file_path]`
2. The file would execute a insert on the table with a dummy value (e.g. `INSERT INTO mytable(id) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())`. After this, the line can be deleted if wished.

Answer (score 1):

After the restart you can use this statement to change the next value to use for `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = new_value;
```

The `CREATE TABLE` syntax is similar, but since memory tables are recreated after the restart, it won't be much use to you.

If the timing of this call is important I would recommend adding it to the [startup script](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file); I wouldn't know any other way.

Comment: I could eventually run this as `ALTER TABLE x AUTO_INCREMENT = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. However how can I automatically trigger this when starting up?

Comment: @Schiavini http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option%5Fmysqld%5Finit-file